# Difference between date-fns' isValid and luxon's isValid

Tags: date-fns, luxon

As mentioned in my question. I really don't understand difference between **date-fns' isValid and luxon's isValid**. I have one date string variable and one variable which I invoke the date string with `new Date()`.

My date string is like this: `Fri Feb 11 2022 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)`

I have few questions:

1. Why the date string is not valid both `date-fns` and `luxon`?
2. The invoked date string variable with `new Date()` in `date-fns` it returns false but in `luxon` it return true

I shared my code in [codesand-box](https://codesandbox.io/s/date-fns-v2-forked-wxl9n?file=/src/index.js)

**This is my all code**

```js
import { isValid } from "date-fns";
import { DateTime } from "luxon";

const onlyDateString =
  "Fri Feb 11 2022 :00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)";

const dateString = new Date(
  "Fri Feb 11 2022 :00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)"
);

const dateStringDateFns = isValid(onlyDateString);
const dateStringLuxon = DateTime.fromISO(onlyDateString).isValid;

const fs = isValid(dateString);
const lu = DateTime.fromISO(dateString).isValid;



document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
<p> Date string </p>
<div> ${dateStringDateFns}</div>
<div>${dateStringLuxon}</div>
<br/>
<p> Date string with new Date </p>
<div>${fs}</div>
<div>${lu}</div>

`;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DateTime's `fromISO` takes string. I was comparing string with `Date`. That was the mistake. Solution is `fromJSDate`

```
DateTime.fromJSDate(dateString).isValid
```